# Python: Unable to import the win32com.client package

Tags: python, import, pywin32, win32com

I cannot import the Python library `win32com.client`.
When I execute the following code

`import win32com.client`

I got this error `AttributeError: module 'pywintypes' has no attribute '__import_pywin32_system_module__'`, giving that the library `pywin32` is already installed.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What's the name of your script?